# Switching 100 different LM35 with one uC

Tags: avr, switches, multiplexer

I want to read the temperature of about 100 different [LM35](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lm35) with only one [ATmega16](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2466.pdf) or [ATmega32](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2503.pdf).
I want to read 8 LM35 at one time and switch to the next 8 and so on.

what kind of multiplexer or switch shall I use?

any other suggestion will be very appreciated.

Comment: Which circuit configuration are you using for the LM35 - nobody on this site, as far as I'm aware is telepathic.

Comment: No, I'm not going to chase down the datasheet for a LM35.

Comment: "At one time" isn't happening.

Comment: Sorry dudes You are all right. it was better to just ask for any suggestion to read 100 different temperature sensors (ranges from 0°C to 100°C)

Comment: If you need 0C then you'll need a negative supply rail and this rules out quite a few multiplexers. Not impossible but I'm asking if zero C is a real requirement. As Alexan indicates in his answer, working from +2C is OK because you can use standard 74xxxx CMOS multiplexers.

Comment: No +2C is ok. They will be used for measuring ambient temperature. by 0C I wanted to show that I don't need negative values ;)

Comment: So why don't put the real requirements into your question rather than they be teased out by folk commenting or answering. While you are there please add what supply voltages you have available and how much current too.

Comment: Look at CD4051 and CD405x family generally. May do what you want. Also, various people make higher spec versions of these. CD4016/CD4066 family are single analog switches per channel but may be useful. Again, much higher spec versions available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using LM35 for the +2°C to +150°C range which outputs positive voltage only then an analog switch like [74HC4066](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/MM/MM74HC4066.pdf) or [74HC4016](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT4016_CNV.pdf) seems fine.
The Maximum ON resistance of the switch is the range of 100 to 200 Ohm which would work fine with the ADC input of the AVR.

If you intent to use the full range −55°C to +150°C then the negative voltage will be a problem with the switch.

Since you intend to use 100 switches in groups of 8 you can bridge the control inputs together for each group, then you can lower the control pins needed to 100/8 = 13 pins
To reduce that even further you can add a couple of shift register like [74HC595](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT595.pdf) and use the outputs to drive the control inputs of the analog switches.

---

Is the use or the analog sensors a requirement?
If not I would suggest the use of a digital sensor like [DS18B20](http://www.maximintegrated.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/2812) that will give a higher accuracy and easier deployment using just a few wires without the need for switches.

Comment: Sorry if it is a basic question but I have never used Ds18B20. How I can use 100 of them without using a switch?

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh It is a digital sensor that returns the result using a "1-Wire" protocol. Each sensor has a unique ID that can be used to identify it in the chain. Take a look at [this](http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/buildingblocks/DS18B20-temperature-sensing)

Comment: But note that putting 100 1-wire devices on a single I/O will probably load it down too much.